# Creating New dictionary from two dictionaries with Key as First dict's Value, and Value as the second dict's Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Example:

```
A = {1: "IWillBeAKeySoon", 7: "IHope"}
B = {1: "ItSeemsIAmAValue",6: "LostVal"}
```

I would like to combine A and B to get a dict C that looks like this:

```
C = {"IWillBeAKeySoon": "ItSeemsIAmAValue"}
```

I have done it manually:

```
C={A[key]:value for key,value in B.items() if key in A}
```

I think there should be some built-in functions or more efficient way to do it, but I can't find it.

Comment: You can spare the `if key in B`, but besides that, you are good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating over either the values or items in parallel **will not work** because the keys are not necessarily matching and also not necessarily in the same order.

Instead, find keys common to both dictionaries:

```
keys = set(A.keys()) & set(B.keys())
```

Then use a dict comprehension to look up the values from each dict with those keys, and assemble them into key-value pairs for the result:

```
C = {A[k]:B[k] for k in keys}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> A = {1: "IWillBeAKeySoon", 6: "MeToo"}
>>> B = {1: "ItSeemsIAmAValue",6: "Val"}
>>> C = dict(zip(A.values(), B.values()))
>>> print(c)
{'MeToo': 'Val', 'IWillBeAKeySoon': 'ItSeemsIAmAValue'}
```

Regarding performance, `dict(zip(...)))` seems to be the fastest:

```
import timeit

A = {x: '%s%12d' % ('a', x) for x in range(100)}
B = {x: '%s%12d' % ('b', x) for x in range(100)}

def v1():
    C={A[key]:value for key,value in B.items() if key in B}

def v2():
    C = dict(zip(A.values(), B.values()))

def v3():
    C = {x[0]: x[1] for x in zip(A.values(), B.values())}

print(timeit.timeit(v1))
print(timeit.timeit(v2))
print(timeit.timeit(v3))
18.561055098
9.385801745000002
17.763003313
```

Comment: I have a problem with this approach, where I get some mismatching keys. I'll update the question.